# how to make push notification to all user, when data has entered the database?

Tags: java, android

"I'm currently using the MySQL database. do I have to replace the MySQL database with Firebase realtime database? could you please to give me tutorial or codes, i'm new in these. this java language is hard to understanding."

Comment: Which language are you using with myself?

Comment: java language..

Comment: Java is your backend right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the MySql database to Firebase database. You have to do the following things -

1. You have to configure your Java back-end to send firebase push notifications. Follow this tutorial to implement -

http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/

2. In the Android app, you can setup by following this tutorial -

https://www.androidauthority.com/android-push-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-925075/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to official firebase messaging document -

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging

You can use this understand the firebase messaging.

You don't need to replace your mysql db with firebase.

Now once the data enters into db, you can send the notifications to multiple devices as mentioned in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_multiple_devices)